# 'For many people in the United States, undergoing a medical procedure can be a stressful, confusing, and sometimes overwhelming ordeal'

Tags: syntax

> For many people in the United States, undergoing a medical procedure can be a stressful, confusing, and sometimes overwhelming ordeal.

Is the following the correct way to describe the parts of this sentence:

The dependent clause:

> For many people in the United States

The independent clause:

> undergoing a medical procedure can be a stressful, confusing, and sometimes overwhelming ordeal.

Verb in independent clause:

> Can be

Subject:

> Undergoing a medical procedure

Object:

> stressful, confusing, and sometimes overwhelming ordeal.

Im not sure what is the verb, subject, and object in the independent clause. To be honest I think the object is adjective but if so, is the sentence structure subject, verb, adjective?

Thanks!

Comment: *For many people in the United States* is not a dependent clause. Right? I think it is the object in the sentence. And, *stressful, confusing, and sometimes overwhelming ordeal* is a subject complement.

Comment: I see, that makes sense cause it doesn't have a verb in it

Comment: It is a phrase :)

Answer (score 2):

*Be* does not take an object but a predicate complement (PC), which may be either nominal or adjectival.

> He is a man.  *The PC is the noun phrase* a man.
>   He is good.   *The PC is the adjective* good.

In your sentence the PC is a noun phrase *a stressful, confusing and sometimes overwhelming ordeal*; its head is the noun *ordeal*, which is determined by *a* and modified by the conjunct phrase composed of *and* conjoining the adjectives *stressful* and *confusing* and the adjective phrase *sometimes overwhelming*.

[image]

(That's not quite how I'd represent the conjunct phrase, but it's what the software I could find would allow, and it's close enough.)

Comment: I see, so is the predicate complement the same as object?

Comment: @dngr193 No -- an Object is acted on by the Subject, a Predicate Complement describes or identifies the Subject.

Comment: +1 'Predicate complement' <-- is that the same as a predicative complement?

Comment: @Araucaria Ayup. I can never decide which term I like less.

Comment: @StoneyB Yep, they're both pants, in the BE sense of the term ...

Comment: I see, also is the "undergoing a medical condition" part the subject or another word?

Comment: @StoneyB so the predicate complement -- either a noun or adjective -- can replace the object in a sentence, right?

Comment: subject complement is also called a predicative complement.